# Delete azure migrate project

Tags: azure, migration

I am using Microsoft azure. I searched "Azure Migrate".
I create a azure migrate project. There is no option to delete it. How to delete azure migrate project

Answer (score 0):

You can remove projects and assessments by opening the resource group where you choose to save the migration project, enable "show hidden objects" and then look for the following resources:

- microsoft.offazure/serversites
- microsoft.migrate/migrateprojects
- microsoft.migrate/assessmentprojects

There is a key vault used by these resources which can be deleted also, the name is similar to the project you created.